# How can I import/require a uploaded JS File into my javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to upload some JS Files (Self-Programmed Bots for a game) and then be able to execute the code inside them.
Currently the User is required to have the Programm in a certain directory and I take the file from there like this:

```
this.bot = require('../bots/' + file.name);
```

Is there a better way to do this that, if possible, also works when the Website is running on a Server (I'm not sure if my current solution would)?

Comment: You can `eval()` the contents of the file, but that comes with security risks: but not any higher than what you're doing now.

Answer (score 0):

> try like this

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
    
        </head>
        <body>
            <script type="module" src="script2.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

> script1.js

```
export default function Hello() {
    return "Hello buddy!";
}
```

> script2.js

```
import { Hello } from './script1.js';
let val = Hello;
console.log(val);
```

Comment: The Problem is, that the file is uploaded by the User, so I cant import it (i dont have the name/Path/content yet)